# How to set the flag true/false based on field values?

Tags: javascript, sql, logic, statements

I have multiple records that have type and status. In case where record type is 'DEV' then the status should be checked. In that case if status is 'Y' then variable should be set to `true`. Here is example of few records:

```
RecID  Type  Status
1      PROD    N
2      PROD    N 
3      PROD    N
4      DEV     Y
5      TEST    N
```

I have developed logic that works, here is example:

```
var showRec = false;

if (type === 'DEV') {
   if(status === 'Y') {
      showRec = true;
   }
}else{
   showRec = true;
}
```

Then I'm able to use `showRec` variable to show hide the elements. I'm wondering if logic above can be simplified? I couldn't find better way to approach this problem. Also I was wondering if this could be done in `SQL` with `CASE WHEN` and then simply use that `column` that will have `Yes\No` or `true\false`. If anyone have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ternary which checks the `type` and takes, if `true` the reuslt of the other check or `true`.

```
showRec = type === 'DEV' ? status === 'Y' : true;
```

Comment: If `type` is not `DEV` then showRec should be set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the logic this way:

```
const showRec = type !== 'DEV'|| status === 'Y';
```

This demands that either `type` be something other than `"DEV"`, or if it is, then `status` must also be `"Y"`.

Comment: Apologies, typo!